# Disabling specific region of screen in android for touchevent

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application in which I want to touch the screen vertically from top to bottom, and with the movement of finger I'm changing background.
I got that part of app.
The issue is that if a user touches the middle or the bottom part (coordinates) of the screen, It changes the background.
**I want that user starts from top and move to bottom** and if the user touches the middle or the bottom part (coordinates) of the screen, application shouldn't show any reaction but a toast should be shown saying
"Start touching from the top of the screen".

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to handle your touch events?

Comment: How are you handling the touch events? You should be able to ignore the sequence if the touch down event does not happen in a specific region of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    if(MatchReservedPixels(x,y))
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//and here is your MatchReservedPixels function 
private boolean MatchReservedPixels(int x,int y)
{
    //Here goes your pixel matching logic
}
```

and don't forget to apply touchevent on avtivity.